# Elegant method to alternate the whole book's font color depending on the input language

Tags: fonts, color, babel, languages, books

The document class: `book`

Outcome desired: switch the color of the font depending on the language throughout the whole document (`red` for `eng` and `black` for `rus` in my case).

Given the length of the document, tagging each and every particular section of the text is not an option.

I used the `babel` code provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648233/how-to-combine-fonts-with-luaotfload/648357#648357) but now the English text is way larger compared to the Cyrillic. How do I control the parameters of the English text  properties of which I modified with this code?

```
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{english}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Colour=000000]{Noto Serif}
```

That's how it looks now:

[image]

How do I make the English text of the same properties as the Cyrillic?

Please find this MWE useful:

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{english}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Colour=000000]{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[
Colour=808080,
%  SmallCapsFont={EB Garamond SC},
%  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
%  Ligatures=TeX,
]

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash} 
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=6in,
  paperheight=9in,
  inner=0.625in,
  top=0.6in,
  outer=0.75in,
  bottom=0.9in, 
  heightrounded,   
]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}{\vfil\penalty500\vfilneg\centering\normalfont\large}{\thepart.}{4ex}{\large\centering}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0ex}{0ex plus 4ex minus 1ex}{-4ex} 
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\vfil\penalty500\vfilneg\centering\normalfont\normalsize}{\thechapter.}{4ex}{\normalsize\centering}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0ex}{4ex plus 4ex minus 1ex}{-2ex} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-4}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\addtocounter{page}{-2} 


\begin{titlepage}
            \begin{center}
            \vspace*{6ex}
            {\scshape\fontsize{3ex}{3ex}\selectfont\textcolor{Red} {TITLE}\par}
            \vspace*{3ex} 
            {\scshape\fontsize{3ex}{3ex}\selectfont\textcolor{Black} {НАЗВАНИЕ}\par}
           \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage


\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part[PART ONE. {Часть первая}]{\textcolor{Red}{PART ONE} \begin{center}{ЧАСТЬ ПЕРВАЯ} \end{center}} 
\chapter[CHAPTER ONE. {Глава первая}]{\textcolor{Red}{CHAPTER ONE} \begin{center}{ГЛАВА ПЕРВАЯ} \end{center}} 
\vspace{-2ex plus 5ex minus 1ex}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, ma- gna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultri- ces. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultri- cies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volut- pat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fer- mentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend con- sequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bi- bendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
 
 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.
 
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.

 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.

 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.
\chapter[CHAPTER TWO. {Глава вторая}]{\textcolor{Red}{CHAPTER TWO} \begin{center} {ГЛАВА ВТОРАЯ} \end{center}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, ma- gna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultri- ces. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultri- cies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volut- pat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fer- mentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend con- sequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bi- bendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
 
 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.
 
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.

 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.

 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.
  \chapter[CHAPTER THREE. {Глава третья}]{\textcolor{Red}{CHAPTER THREE} \begin{center} {ГЛАВА ТРЕТЬЯ} \end{center}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, ma- gna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultri- ces. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultri- cies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volut- pat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fer- mentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend con- sequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bi- bendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
 
 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.
 
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.

 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.

 Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, еа магна цонсул минимум еам, мовет ириуре ин сеа. Миним реферрентур нец ин, стет путент иус ид, сед ут реяуе яуидам яуалисяуе. Ин сит легимус елигенди легендос, цум еи яуот рецтеяуе. Еам нибх ехплицари еи, цу нец интерессет аппеллантур улламцорпер. Хас нихил легере тритани еи, хис ет нолуиссе инвенире цонвенире. Сит легере дисцере но, цасе утрояуе цу мел. Цу адхуц дебитис иус. Не темпор путент персеяуерис мел. Про цоммодо епицуреи ан, нам дицта волуптатум ид.

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}   

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure you can get away without tagging. Like it is now, LaTeX thinks that all the document is in `russian` (last option of `babel`). If you do not mark the English text with the `otherlanguge` or whatever environment, several things (first of all hyphenation) will be wrong.  LaTeX has no idea that the text in cyrillic is russian and the other is english --- and doing that automatically will be not easy. Said that, you probably can (in `lualatex`) load the font with some magic to set the cyricllic chars in another color, but then you'll have a problem with the commas and points...

Comment: Say, for now I don't care about hyphenation and etc., what would be the easiest way to separate text by color? `\iflanguage` explained here [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652185/change-the-text-depending-on-the-language?rq=1) or here [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42784/language-dependent-custom-command) is not working for me. `babel` solution set forward here [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416066/change-colour-of-italics-font-for-the-whole-document?rq=1) doesn't seem to have option for language.

Comment: Something like that (provided the engine is `luatex`)?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648357/5735 . With `xetex`, try with the package `ucharclasses`.

Comment: And how would I modify this code `\directlua{luaotfload.add_multiscript("noto_greek", 
{
    grek = "NotoSerif:mode=node;color=FF8800;script=grek;language=PGR",
})}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}
[RawFeature={multiscript=noto_greek;color=A0A0A0}]` for russian? Changed `greek` to `russian`, but what do I change `grek` to? And what's `language=PGR`?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651503/biblatex-make-all-non-latin-characters-appear-in-grey-color/651528 for an example of the `ucharclasses` approach, which indeed has the issue of punctuation characters that are seen as Latin script.

Comment: Unfortunately `ucharclasses` wouldn't compile neither in `XeTex` nor in `XeLaTex`. So I incorporated `babel` code and now having problems with how the languages are displayed. I updated the question with how the doc looks now.